# Tips for deploying Go REST API on GCP Cloud Functions? Handling dependencies and project structure challenges. Appreciate insights

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, terraform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I want to deploy my rest api on gcp cloud functions.
My folder structure is -

```
Root Folder
│
├── cmd
│   └── main.go
│
├── models
│   └── models.go
│
├── validations
│   └── validations.go
│
├── functions
│   ├── getAllEmployees.go
│   ├── createEmployees.go
│   ├── updateEmployees.go
│   └── deleteEmployees.go
│
├── db
│   └── firestore.go
│
└── go.mod
```

I want to deploy my functions with shared flow. All functions have dependencies on other folders like models.go, validations.go, firestore.go and main.go is for my local testing. I want to deploy all functions as isolated gcfs with the help of 'gcloud build' command without having any dockerfile. How can I do this? Can I make improvements in my folder structure? Please guide me with this considering me as newbee for gcp. And Also help me with how can I automate this with terraform.

Comment: Will your cloud functions offer one or several endpoints?

Comment: Severel endpoints for each function...

Comment: So, cloud functions is not the right tool, prefer Cloud Run. that being said, you can solve your issue by either creating a first container layer with all the common library (not my recommended way), or work with go module in artifact registry, and reference these modules in your Cloud Functions dedicated go.mod file. https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/go